# What is a fast way to identify code generated UIViews in swift for non-programmers?

Tags: ios, swift, appium

## Question

I have built an app (all the UI is code generated, we don't have a storyboard) that must be localized. We have created a spreadsheet that has all the keys that maps to several languages. I have someone who is proof reading the localization (who is non technical), but they are having trouble mapping the text in the spreadsheet to the exact location where that text appears on the app.

Is there a way where I can let such non-technical staff quickly identify UIViews?

## What I have tried

I tried setting an accessibility identifier like so

```
 reorderButton.accessibilityLabel = "reorder_button"
 contentView.addSubview(self.reorderButton)
```

but using tools like [sherlock](https://sherlock.inspiredcode.io/) didn't help me find it:

[image]

I also found that one can search for an element using tools like Appium as described in [this post](https://medium.com/the-ministry-of-testing/adding-accessibility-identifiers-to-an-ios-app-c8e09d9c20f3), but the problem this is a very static approach, it doesn't play nicely with code generated UI.

What ideas do you have?

Comment: Offtopic but can I ask you why you do not choose Storyboards?

Comment: code generated UI unleashes the power of design patterns much better than storyboards. in large projects i found code gen ui to be much better

Answer (score 0):

As per me, making the spreadsheet for the Localisation is little complex process, because first the developer has to take a copy of the **Key and Value** and add it to Spreadsheet and then translator translates it, and again developer has to take a copy from it to the code and later in future, if some new key/value added or updated, then it makes it hard to find with the colouring the keys approach.

What I suggest is:

1) Developer (you) should Localise the project to English(default) Language.

2) Add the key/value pairs to that file, based on screens(Starting welcome screen) and add all strings being used in that particular screen.

3) Add some separator to distinguish between the screens.

4) Now, Localise the project to all other languages, as per your need.

5) Copy the English version to all the generated files of other languages.

6) Provide that Localizable.strings (your languages) to translator

7) Ask him (non-technical translator) to only update the values (i.e the text on right side of = sign) and change it to desired language.

8) Get the updated files from him and replace the existing contents to newly provided files.

This way translator(non-technical) has not to worry about any missing strings and entire application can be translated to desired languages.